# Calculating the value of a function for different inputs matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I want to Calculating the value of a function for different inputs in matlab and insert output in a matrix for example: `x(1,1)=1 y(1,1)=1 x(1,2)=2 y(1,2)=4`  and etc. 
this is my m file in matlab:

```
clc,clear all,close all

x0=0;

xn=10;

n=10;

h=(xn-x0)/n;

k=1;

for k=1:n

 x=[1:10];

 x=x0+h;

 y=x^2

 x0=x;

end
```

My problem is that every time the for loop runs The output value is stored in the y and I can't use the output value for example: `x=2` in somewhere else.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what it is exactly what you want. Matlab functions are described here: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- `x=[1:10]` does not do anything as you overwrite it in the next line
- If you remove `x = [1:10]` you can achieve what you want to achieve by using indexing, i.e. `x(k) = x0 + h` and `y(k) = x(k)^2` and `x0 = x(k)`

There is a simpler way though using vectorization though!

```
x = 1:10
y = x.^2
```